# Double Equivalence Point Calculations for Oxalic Acid

Tags: acid-base

Question:

Oxalic Acid, H2C2O4 has two pKa values, 1.25 and 4.27. A 0.100 M solution of oxalic acid was titrated with a 0.100 M solution of HaOH. What is the pH at the second equivalence point?

a) 1.23

b) 5.60

c) 8.40

d) 12.52

I tried to make an ICE table with, but since I don't know the amount of solution in Liters, I am not calculate the number of moles used up in the equation. I have no clue how to approach this question, therefore I can't show any work. The answer key says C is the correct answer.

A solution would be helpful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Even if you had no clue how to solve the question, you should show your work of attempting to get the clue.

Comment: BTW, the right answer is clear just while reading the question, without any calculation.

Answer (score 1):

In acid-base titrations, the pH at the equivalent point is usually taken as the average value of the last p$K\ce{_a}$ preceding the equivalence point and the pH of the final NaOH solution. Here the last $p$K$\ce{_a}$ value is $4.27$. The $\ce{NaOH}$ solution has a pH equal to $13$. Average value : $(13 + 4.27)/2 = 8.64$. It is nearly $8.40$ as proposed in solution c).